# How are credentials stored and encrypted in Nexus OSS 2.14?

Tags: nexus, credentials, nexus2

I couldn’t finy anything in the documentation, knowledge base nor on the web on how credentials (local users) are stored by Nexus OSS 2.14.

The only hint was a release note of 2.5 about introducing salted hashes.

Where in the data dir are credentials saved? What algorithms are used to encrypt them?

I’m thankful for any hint.

Comment: I'd check files here https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/tree/master/components/nexus-crypto/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/crypto/internal